# How to read different files into a structure of Directories and json files

Tags: r

I am wondering which is the most efficient way to read from 55 folders with 1, 2 or 3 files json...

[image]

For now, I am opening each folder, changing the name, putting in the same folder that I am using in R, and reading them, and at the very end concat all the files, but I am completely sure that there is a better way

I want to know if there any chance to say to R Studio:

1. Read this folder with the name starting in 2018-10-27 and finish in 2018-12-20
2. Read each of the files inside using `parseTweets`
3. concat each file with the previous one

For now my provisional solution:

```
 install.packages("streamR")
 library(streamR)

 #reading file

 tweets.df.31 <- parseTweets("10_31_0_raw.json")
 tweets.df.30 <- parseTweets("10_30_0_raw.json")
 tweets.df.29 <- parseTweets("10_29_0_raw.json")
 tweets.df.28 <- parseTweets("10_28_0_raw.json")

 #concat multiple files

 new <- rbind(tweets.df.31, tweets.df.30,tweets.df.29,tweets.df.28)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what the parseTweets function returns, but I think something like this should work.

```
folders_dir <- "path/to/folders"
files <- dir(folders_dir, recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

l <- lapply(files, parseTweets)

res <- plyr::ldply(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

`library(fs)` is very handy for getting/nicefying paths, files, and directories. It may be as easy as using `fs::dir_ls` as in:

```
paths <- dir_ls(recursive = TRUE, glob = "*.json")
```

Next, identify which `paths[[x]]` is 2018-12-20, and then `paths <- paths[[1:x]]` (there's probably something more sophisticated, but let's keep it simple ;-) ). Finally,

```
lapply(paths, parseTweets)
```

should do it.